# How to play against an engine using scidb?

Tags: engines, software, database, scidb

I'v just installed [the scidb chess database](http://scidb.sourceforge.net), and I can't figure how to play against an engine from there.
Is this feature even supported ? If it is, how to use it ?

Comment: If it is not, try [Scid vs. PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net).

Comment: On this [page](http://scidb.sourceforge.net/wanted.html), you can see that Scidb is not intended to be used to play against an engine.

Comment: @antoyo: Thanks a lot. So, what shall I use for game analysis and playing against the computer (and maybe online) ?

Comment: You can use `scidb` for game analysis (click on the train button in the board tab), `chessx` to play against the computer (and game analysis too) and `raptor chess interface` or `Jin` to play on FICS (Free Internet Chess Server). These softwares all work on Linux. Other software are availble on Windows and OS X.

Comment: @antoyo, why not post your comment(s) as an actual answer, since you've answered the OP's question? The site works best that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this [page](http://scidb.sourceforge.net/wanted.html), you can see that Scidb is not intended to be used to play against an engine.

You can use `scidb` for game analysis (click on the train button in the board tab), `chessx` to play against the computer (and game analysis too) and `raptor chess interface` or `Jin` to play on FICS (Free Internet Chess Server). These softwares all work on Linux. Other softwares are availble on Windows and OS X.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please recommend a GUI ?

Comment: For Linux, I recommend scidb, chessx and raptor. We need many softwares to do analysis, play against engine and play online.